# Installed package from Nuget points to different locations for different users

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, nuget

So we have a project (target .NET framework `4.6.2`) that uses `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`, which is a dependency from a chain of other packages.

User 1 installed it via Nuget and shared the code to others. However, now we are in a mess that eventually results in the error of `The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040` for at least one of us.

And trying to fix it, we realized that the reference to `System.Diagnostics.Tracing` is different for each of us.

User 1: It points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll`

User 2: It points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll`

User 3: The only one that it actually points to the installed Nuget package `C:\Users\User3\Documents\Project\Test\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll`

And for some reason User 3 is the one who can't run the project. User 1 and User 2 are fine.

And the `.csproj` file does have this specifically.

```
<Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.Tracing">
    <HintPath>..\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

We are out of ideas why this would happen, and how to fix it. Nuget is supposed to be a good way to deal with dependencies, and somehow it is very messy in this situation.

Anyone has experience on dealing with this?

Comment: HintPath is just that: a hint of where to find the assembly if it can't be found in other places (e.g. the GAC; but there are also other places that it looks).

Comment: 1. All switch to VS2017. 2. Modify the project to use package references instead of `packages.config`. Then it might have a higher possibility to work.

Comment: @Richardissimo Is there any way to tell it not to take that as a "hint"?

Comment: @LexLi I believe we all have VS2017, but we haven't tried package references. Might worth a shot. Thanks!

Comment: The build process will use a defined order of places to look. I'm struggling to find an official source for where it looks; but the 'Compile Time Reference Resolution' part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32342226/5198140) indicates a sequence of places where it will look. Make sure the NuGet package referred to has been added to your version control system, and all 3 users have the file at that location in their workspace. You can make sure everyone gets the same version by making sure those other versions don't exist on the other users machines.