Visual Studio Project Reference Location Ignored
Within a bigger Visual Studio solution (.NET Framework), one test project ignores the path of a third-party assembly reference (file path reference) and, instead, uses a different version of the same third-party assembly, which it finds in a sub-directory of the project. Removing and re-addding the reference does not change anything.
Solution/ project structure looks like this:

Solution

External Assemblies

Third-Party Assembly (v2.0.0)


Some Project

Reference to Third-Party Assembly v2.0.0


Test Project

Reference to Some Project
Reference to Third-Party Assembly v1.0.0 (this is the faulty reference)
Test Files

[...] + Third-Party Assembly (v1.0.0)







The reference on the test project always points to the old version of the third-party DLL.
The third-party DLL has a strong name, if relevant, but is not installed in the GAC.
The test file package cannot be changed as it is provided by an external customer.
I already added a binding redirect (third-party DLL is backwards compatible), but build fails with error "[...] uses higher version than referenced assembly [...]".
I guess, I am doing something wrong on adding the reference but I cannot figure it out...
Any help or idea is welcome!

Questions: Do you know if you are using GAC version or not for the faulty reference? You said it had a strong name, so you probably are. See this, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342087/how-are-references-located-in-net

Good question, I will add to the description, but the third-party DLL is not in the GAC.

OK, so when you added these references, was it 'old style' right-click 'Add Reference..." and selecting DLL or project, or was it newer NuGet Package Manager find in the NuGet package browser and select? And if NuGet, are NuGet Package settings set to Pacakges.config or PackageReference? And if using NuGet and regardless of that setting, do you have a Packages.config file in the problem project? If using PackageReference and your codebase is longstanding, you may still have a Packages.config file playing havoc. If so, it should be deleted so you are exclusively using PackageReference approach.

Seems I found the root cause. As the test files directory has been included in the project (despite build action was set to "none"), it seems that the VisualStudio considers them as relevant for the probing. Excluded the test files directory (still under version control, but not in solution/ project), it follows the path from the file reference.

@majixin I added the references in the "old style" (as file not project references)

You may as well write-up your findings as a full answer, and mark as correct - it may help somebody else.

Out of curiosity, why is your test-project "file-referencing" a 1.0 version?  and not referencing the file .. from "../External Assemblies/" ?     since it is a test-project.. that is being used to test the "real" project?

@granadaCoder my test project ought to reference the version 2.0.0 from the External Assemblies, but for the described reason it ended up using the wrong version (the reference to 1.0.0 is faulty)

Thanks to this detailed description of the assembly resolving, I identified that including the test files in the VisualStudio project was causing the errors. Despite setting the build action to "none", it seems that VisualStudio was considering the files for the probing path. After excluding the files from the project (but still under version control), the right version of the assembly is used.
